# WFS service is not OGC compliant

Tags: wfs, ogc, standards

I am quite surprised to discover several WFS services (v1.0.0) running on the web which are not compliant with the OGC WFS-1.0.0 standard.
In the framework of my project, I use a JAXB binding built with the XSD schemas from the OGC, and notably the schemas for WFS v1.0.0.
As you imagine, not OGC-compliant services are a problem in such a project.

The problem of compliance is for example the XML element:

> /WFS_Capabilities/ServiceIndentification

which is replaced by:

> /WFS_Capabilities/Service

For example in the capabilities:
http://www.disasterschartercatalog.org/ogc/cecec4wfs?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0&SERVICE=WFS

Is anyone know the reasons of this? is it something common?

Answer (score 4):

This following one ***is*** correct:

> /WFS_Capabilities/Service

as defined by the following portion of the [schema definition](http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-capabilities.xsd) for version 1.0.0

```xml
<xsd:element name="Service" type="wfs:ServiceType"/>
```

Take a look at **12.3.3 Service section** in the *[Web Feature Service Implementation Specification](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=7176)* (OGC 02-058)

Comment: My mistake, sorry, I thought that WFS-1.0.0 and 1.1.0 use OWS-1.0 but actually it is not the case... my mistake, I will delete my question soon.